# Using INSERT after a THEN is this possible

Tags: sql, insert, case

Im sorry new to this site....MS SQL Server 2008 R2 / That is the database the statements are being ran against.Trying to use a INSERT after a THEN...possible?  Suggestions?

userindex is the table
sysname is column

HERE is the SQL statement

```
Select CASE when sysname <> system_user Then insert into USERINDEX (sysname, truncun, first, last, cname) values (system_user, right(system_user, len(system_user) - charindex('\', system_user)), '{Enter First Name:}', '{Enter Last Name:}', host_name() ) ELSE End From userindex
```

Comment: you mean `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM ...`? Which DB are you using?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: You can add a WHERE clause to your INSERT, so that it only inserts conditionally

Comment: Please tag the question so we know what database.  It's frustrating to try to answer this as is.

Comment: Basically what I am trying to perform I could easily do with an if/then, but Im somewhat new to SQL.  I want the statement to check the table for the system_user (sysname column) and host_name (cname column) and if both conditions are false (user doesnt exit in table with that computer name) then inserts a new record into the table.....I hope that helps.  I amended the question to reflect the DBMS - Thank you all

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to say what the exact syntax would be without knowing the DBMS used, but generally speaking you don't need `CASE` for what you're trying to do.  Something like this would work:

```
insert into USERINDEX
(sysname, truncun, first, last, cname)
(select system_user,
        right(system_user, len(system_user) - charindex('\', system_user)),
        '{Enter First Name:}', '{Enter Last Name:}', host_name() 
 from userindex
 where sysname <> system_user
);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't
If you are using T-SQL you can wrap two or more sentences into a procedure and call it